# Store Azure WebJobs connection string on to Azure Portal App Settings

Tags: webjob

I'm trying to store the Web Job connection strings on to Azure Portal. I've moved the connection strings there but Web Job keeps failing with error below:

> [03/05/2021 01:59:23 > 2aff49: INFO]
> stem.ArgumentException: ConnectionString should not be null, and empty string or consists only of white-space characters..

This is how I've setup:
[image]

And app config:

```
<connectionStrings configBuilders="connectionStringsBuilder">
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation" connectionString="" />
  <add name="xdb.referencedata" connectionString="" />
  <add name="messaging" connectionString="" />
</connectionStrings>
```